# Find Employee's Experience difference in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Question is to find experience Difference of **SMITH** and **ALLEN**.
So i have written this query.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(
    SELECT hiredate FROM emp 
           WHERE ename LIKE 'SMITH', 
    SELECT hiredate FROM emp 
           WHERE ename LIKE 'ALLEN'
) FROM emp;
```

and it shows ERROR..
what is wrong with this query.
Plz Help....

Comment: I want Difference in Months Instead of Days...what can I Do?

Answer (score 3):

Subqueries need to be surrounded by parentheses:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(
    (SELECT hiredate FROM emp 
           WHERE ename LIKE 'SMITH'), 
    (SELECT hiredate FROM emp 
           WHERE ename LIKE 'ALLEN')
) FROM emp;
```

You don't actually need the final `from emp`, unless you want a lot of rows:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(
    (SELECT hiredate FROM emp 
           WHERE ename LIKE 'SMITH'), 
    (SELECT hiredate FROM emp 
           WHERE ename LIKE 'ALLEN')
);
```

Another way to write this query:

```
select datediff(max(case when ename like 'SMITH' then hiredate end),
                max(case when ename like 'ALLEN' then hiredate end)
               )
from emp
where ename in ('SMITH', 'ALLEN');
```

The advantage of this query is that it only reads the `emp` table once.

EDIT: (about months)

MySQL doesn't have a built-in ability to calculate the months between values.  An approximation would be `days / 30.4`.  You can use `period_diff()`.  But if this is important, then ask another question and give examples of what you mean by difference in months (What is the difference between '2014-01-31' and '2014-02-01'?  Between '2014-01-12' and '2014-02-11'?  Between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31'?).

Comment: Thanks... I really liked the Last Query. It's Quite Helpful :)

Comment: The last one should have a `,` where it once had a `-`.

Comment: WHAT if I want Difference in **Months** Instead of Days?

Comment: @SriVastav: I have added my answer with minor modification.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use below query to get the days difference in months:

```
SELECT ceil(DATEDIFF(
    (SELECT hiredate FROM emp WHERE ename LIKE 'SMITH'),(SELECT hiredate FROM emp WHERE ename LIKE 'ALLEN')
)/30.4);
```